# R Syntax Simple Slopes MEM

Tags: r, syntax, mixed-models

Question regarding the syntax of a mixed effects model on R.

I have run the following code to examine the simple slope to determine the effect of one of my variables (variability) within another one of my variables (ambiguity):

```
lmer.E1.v2 <- lmer(logRT ~ Variability.c / Ambiguity.c + (Variability.c + Ambiguity.c|ID),
                   data=data %>% filter(Experiment == "E1"),
                   control=lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
summary(lmer.E1.v2)
```

When I reverse these two variables, so that the code looks like this:

```
lmer.E1.v2 <- lmer(logRT ~ Ambiguity.c / Variability.c + (Ambiguity.c + Variability.c|ID),
                   data=data %>% filter(Experiment == "E1"),
                   control=lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
summary(lmer.E1.v2)
```

.. and I get different output in the first section of code than the second. What is the difference in interpretation in reversing the order of my two variables in the syntax?

Comment: Can you include the output of your `summary()` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue is that the `/` operator is not commutative (i.e. `a/b != b/a`): `a/b` expands to `a + a:b`, while `b/a` expands to `b + a:b`. You should get the same overall fit (predictions, likelihood, etc.), at least up to some degree of numeric fuzz, but the model parameterization will be different.

There do exist cases where `(a+b|g)` gives different answers from `(b+a|g)` (see [here](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/449), but this is unusual).